# browserSync + Gulp, getting error => TypeError: _.contains is not a function

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-sass

I've installed [browserSync](https://www.browsersync.io/) to get my browsers to auto refresh if I update CSS or html templates.

In my gulp file:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
```

And down by my watch tasks:

```
// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['app-css'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        // server: "./app"
        proxy: 'http://localhost/static/dashboard/app/'
    });

    gulp.watch("sass-smacss/sass/**/*.scss", ['app-css']);
    gulp.watch("app/**/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

I have a local server so that is the link I'm using for my `proxy` above.

Anyways I ran `gulp serve` and it automatically launched a new Chrome window with this path: http://localhost:3000/static/dashboard/app/#/login

Next I then just hit save in one of my sass files and it threw the following error:

> ```
> [21:52:37] Starting 'app-css'...
> /Users/leongaban/Projects/TickerTags/dashboard/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/file-utils.js:48
>         if (!_.contains(options.get("injectFileTypes").toJS(), obj.ext)) {
>                ^
> ```

```
TypeError: _.contains is not a function
    at Object.fileUtils.getFileInfo (/Users/leongaban/Projects/TickerTags/dashboard/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/file-utils.js:48:16)
    at Object.fileUtils.changedFile (/Users/leongaban/Projects/TickerTags/dashboard/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/file-utils.js:26:57)
    at EventEmitter.events.file:changed (/Users/leongaban/Projects/TickerTags/dashboard/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/internal-events.js:13:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Object.emitChangeEvent (/Users/leongaban/Projects/TickerTags/dashboard/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/public/public-utils.js:13:17)
    at Transform.reload._transform (/Users/leongaban/Projects/TickerTags/dashboard/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/public/stream.js:70:31)
    at Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:292:12)
```

---

Here is the `/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/file-utils.js:48`

```
/**
 * @param data
 * @param options
 * @returns {{assetFileName: *, fileExtension: String}}
 */
getFileInfo: function (data, options) {

    data.ext      = require("path").extname(data.path).slice(1);
    data.basename = require("path").basename(data.path);

    var obj = {
        ext:           data.ext,
        path:          data.path,
        basename:      data.basename,
        type:          "inject"
    };

    // RELOAD page
    if (!_.contains(options.get("injectFileTypes").toJS(), obj.ext)) {
        obj.url  = obj.path;
        obj.type = "reload";
    }

    obj.path = data.path;
    obj.log  = data.log;

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/976

Comment: Ah thanks for that link, I just re-installed lodash at `3.1.0` trying it again

Comment: That was it! Want to post your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Phil https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/976

Had to upgrade lodash and now it works.